# Error retrieving a list from unattached content database

Tags: content-database

I'm trying to retrieve a library from an unattached content database.

Unfortunately after selecting the site collection and library I get
the following error:

```
 [2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM] Start Time: 2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM.
    [2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM] Progress: Initializing Export.
    [2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM] Progress: Starting Export.
    [2/23/2016 5:00:31 PM] Progress: Calculating Objects to Export.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:14 PM] Progress: Serializing Objects to Disk.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:14 PM] Progress: Starting to process objects of type Min.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Progress: Finished processing objects of type Min.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Progress: Starting to process objects of type Folder.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] [Folder] [Documenti condivisi] Progress: Exporting /MySite/Document Condivisi
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] [Folder] [Documenti condivisi]   Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    [2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] [Folder] [Documenti condivisi]   Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportObjectManager.GetUserByLogin(String loginName)

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetUserFromMetaInfo(MetaInfoProperty mip, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetMetaInfo(Object metaInfoObject, SPWeb parentWeb, SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetDataFromDataSet(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.SerializeObject(Object obj, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, String elementName, Boolean bNeedEnvelope)
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] FatalError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportObjectManager.GetUserByLogin(String loginName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetUserFromMetaInfo(MetaInfoProperty mip, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetMetaInfo(Object metaInfoObject, SPWeb parentWeb, SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetDataFromDataSet(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.SerializeObject(Object obj, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, String elementName, Boolean bNeedEnvelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object topLevelObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.SerializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.Run()
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Progress: Export did not complete.
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Finish Time: 2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM.
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Duration: 00:09:43
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Total Objects: 2175819
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Finished with 0 warnings.
[2/23/2016 5:10:15 PM] Finished with 2 errors.
```

What could it be?

**EDIT:**
I've tried with Export full security checked and unchecked but it fails in both cases

Comment: Given the place the exception occurs (`Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportObjectManager.GetUserByLogin` right after `Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer`) and exception type I'd bet this is related to orphan users in that library items' field (`Created by` or `Modified by` or some custom ones). What SP version is this? Is there anything in ULS?

Comment: version is 2013. Do you think I can identify which are the items with orphan users? Later I'll have a look at the ULS

Comment: Are you using CA UI to perform this operation? If yes, what was the value of "Export full security", was it set?

Comment: Yes it was set.

Comment: Mind to try without that option set?

Comment: Ok, I think I 've already tried that. Anyway, I will try . Now I'm trying a complete back and it seems to be going and I wouldndn't like to interefere to much. I'll let you know thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36156/discussion-between-aziz-kabyshev-and-gyonder).