# Export-SPWeb : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: export

I cannot  export a library.

This is the command I execute:

> Export-SPWeb -Identity $sourceUrl -Path $filecmp -ItemUrl "Documenti
>   Condivisi"  -Verbose -UseSqlSnapshot -Force

with the following output:

```
Export-SPWeb : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At C:\temp\getlistatit.ps1:46 char:1
+ Export-SPWeb -Identity $sourceUrl -Path $filecmp -ItemUrl "Documenti
Condivisi"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletExportWeb:
   SPCmdletExportWeb) [Export-SPWeb], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletExportWe
   b

VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Export-SPWeb.
VERBOSE: Leaving EndProcessing Method of Export-SPWeb.
```

And this comes from the log:

```
/04/2016 12.58.55] [Folder] [Documenti condivisi]   Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[19/04/2016 12.58.55] [Folder] [Documenti condivisi]   Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportObjectManager.GetUserByLogin(String loginName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetUserFromMetaInfo(MetaInfoProperty mip, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetMetaInfo(Object metaInfoObject, SPWeb parentWeb, SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetDataFromDataSet(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.SerializeObject(Object obj, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, String elementName, Boolean bNeedEnvelope)
[19/04/2016 12.58.55] FatalError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[19/04/2016 12.58.55] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportObjectManager.GetUserByLogin(String loginName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetUserFromMetaInfo(MetaInfoProperty mip, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetMetaInfo(Object metaInfoObject, SPWeb parentWeb, SerializationInfo info, ExportObjectManager objectManager)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.GetDataFromDataSet(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentSerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.SerializeObject(Object obj, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, String elementName, Boolean bNeedEnvelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object topLevelObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.SerializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.Run()
[19/04/2016 12.58.55] Progress: Export did not complete.
```

I had a similar problem in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172071/error-retrieving-a-list-from-unattached-content-database). It's probably related even if I was doing another operation.

I have tried to see if there are any orphaned items but

> $db.Repair($false)

gives:

```
<OrphanedObjects Count="0" />
```

Have you got any suggestion on how to solve it?

**EDIT:**
Export of an empty template also fails. It gives me this error :

```
SPSecurityContext: Could not retrieve a valid windows identity for username 'MYDAOMAIN\MYUSER' with UPN 'myemail@mydomain'. UPN is required when Kerberos constrained delegation is used. Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: WTS0003: The caller is not authorized to access the service. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: WTS0003: The caller is not authorized to access the service.   
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.WindowsTokenService.CallerSecurity.CheckCaller(WindowsIdentity callerIdentity)    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.WindowsTokenService.S4UServiceContract.PerformLogon(Func`1 logonOperation, Int32 pid)    
 at SyncInvokeUpnLogon(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet))..
```

I have to add that the library is beyond every reasonable limit (1200000 files).

Comment: ItemUrl - Specifies the URL of the Web application, GUID, or object to be exported. The type must be a valid URL.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

Comment: @Sergey B. Hizof  You  can even use a relative path as I did; Check this out: https://books.google.it/books?id=9hLKCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT1070&lpg=PT1070&dq=Export-SPWeb++ItemUrl+%22Shared+Documents%22&source=bl&ots=3Bw0LeFkod&sig=jTFiULFVErtTSZK_AsyFb1nsagA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA6YG02ZrMAhUCvxQKHYIWAF8Q6AEIOzAH#v=onepage&q=Export-SPWeb%20%20ItemUrl%20%22Shared%20Documents%22&f=false

Comment: one test, i want to do...can you try to documentlib save as template...with and without content...

Comment: @Waqas Sarwar MCSE tried export of template without content. Read edit content in case it gives you some insight.

Comment: looks like your Doc Library having the issue...who is the user?

Comment: well the user is me.The library has some issues. I asked the owner office to make it smaller. But at the moment I'm working with it,